# Email a record stored in database to each one has own record in pdf file by single button using Php and Php mailer

Tags: php, database, pdf, sendmail

how i can retrieve data from data base using PHP code. and then send these data to another person through the required email. i want php code that send data to each one, one by one in pdf form, on the email address included in the record by clicking one button

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without more details and some demonstration of what you have already attempted it is difficult to know exactly what you need. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and use it to refine your question.

Comment: sir! i need the procedure in php, that a WHILE loop extract data from database one by one and convert it into pdf and then send it to the email address that contain each record for example we have three record 1,2 and 3 in a table and and each has email as attribute field also include, now we want that to each one we send his their own record in pdf format

Answer (score 0):

please cheek this link and implement this..
https://www.jotform.com/help/126-How-to-send-Submissions-to-Your-MySQL-Database-Using-PHP